# Error al insertar registros por fallo de constrain

Tags: mysql

En mi código SQL no me deja añadir algunos datos, estoy siguiendo un curso y no puedo pasar de esta parte no comprendo el problema les pido ayuda soy novato en esto

aparece este error

> error de SQL cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint
> fails (´tienda´.´t_procutos´consstraint FK_t_productos´,t_proveedor´
> FOREIGN KEY (´id_proveedor´)REFERENCES ´t_proveedor´(´id_proveedor´)
> ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO t_clientes (id_cliente, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo) 
Values
       ( 58390, 'Octavio', 'Ruiz', 27, 'M' ),
       ( 58391, 'Diego', 'Fernandez', 32, 'M' ),
       ( 58392, 'Omar', 'Garcia', 24, 'M' ),
       ( 58393, 'Maria', 'Luna', 26, 'F' ),
       ( 58394, 'Silvia', 'Zuñiga', 35, 'F' ),
       ( 58395, 'Pedro', 'Perez', 22, 'M' ),
       ( 58396, 'Sonia', 'Cardona', 29, 'F' ),
       ( 58397, 'Hugo', 'Mendez', 30, 'M' ),
       ( 58398, 'Sofia', 'Parriego', 26, 'F' ),
       ( 58399, 'Sandra', 'Rivas', 31, 'F' );

INSERT INTO t_productos (id_producto, modelo, marca, precio, id_proveedor) 
Values
       ( 12340, 'Camara', 'Sani', 5350, 45638 ),
       ( 12341, 'Pantalla', 'Samsoni', 7820, 45632 ),
       ( 12342, 'Audifonos', 'Tronic', 1456, 45633 ),
       ( 12343, 'DVD', 'Yashi', 1000, 45631 ),
       ( 12344, 'Bluray', 'Moshi', 2000, 45636 ),
       ( 12345, 'Celular', 'Moma', 5670, 45639 ),
       ( 12346, 'Mouse', 'Razor', 560, 45630 ),
       ( 12347, 'Laptop', 'vopoi', 17500, 45635 ),
       ( 12348, 'Teclado', 'Razor', 1020, 45634 ),
       ( 12349, 'Videogame', 'Sanor', 4567, 45637 );

INSERT INTO t_proveedores (id_proveedor, nombre, apellido, dirección) 
Values
       ( 45630, 'Manuel', 'Hernández', 'calle coneja #432' ),
       ( 45631, 'Jesus', 'Martinez', 'calle flores #543' ),
       ( 45632, 'Fernanado', 'Lopez', 'calle trejo #654' ),
       ( 45633, 'Ivan', 'Sanchez', 'calle nuvo #765' ),
       ( 45634, 'Rosa', 'Rodriguez', 'calle trolo #876' ),
       ( 45635, 'Merida', 'Rito', 'calle falco #987' ),
       ( 45636, 'Leslie', 'Duran', 'calle mediterraneo #102' ),
       ( 45637, 'Ulises', 'Mendoza', 'calle mar #234' ),
       ( 45638, 'Andrea', 'Guzman', 'calle yate #345' ),
       ( 45639, 'Luz', 'Velazquez', 'calle siempre viva #678' );

INSERT INTO t_sucursal (id_sucursal, nombre, dirección) 
Values
       ( 23560, 'Salmons tropia', 'calle tropia #234' ),
       ( 23561, 'Salmons naranjo', 'calle naranjo #345' ),
       ( 23562, 'Salmons artemisa', 'calle artemisa #456' ),
       ( 23563, 'Salmons pichacho', 'calle picacho #567' ),
       ( 23564, 'Salmons fisica', 'calle fisica #678' );

INSERT INTO t_vendedor (id_vendedor, nombre, apellido, id_sucursal, telefono) 
Values
       ( 67840, 'Alberto', 'Ascencio', 23562, 84592730 ),
       ( 67841, 'Paulina', 'Rivera', 23562, 89452356 ),
       ( 67842, 'Jose', 'Bueno', 23564, 98653265 ),
       ( 67843, 'Eduardo', 'Telones', 23564, 98342761 ),
       ( 67844, 'Martha', 'Mota', 23561, 14568723 ),
       ( 67845, 'Alonso', 'Garcia', 23561, 14789534 ),
       ( 67846, 'Diego', 'Trenes', 23563, 34679512 ),
       ( 67847, 'Monica', 'Diaz', 23563, 34785612 ),
       ( 67848, 'Maricela', 'Hernandez', 23560, 78341267 ),
       ( 67849, 'Joel', 'Rico', 23560, 78563453 );

INSERT INTO t_ventas (id_venta, id_cliente, id_producto, id_vendedor, fecha)
Values
       ( 1, 58391, 12342, 67840, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 2, 58397, 12344, 67845, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 3, 58393, 12340, 67846, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 4, 58390, 12345, 67843, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 5, 58392, 12343, 67849, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 6, 58395, 12347, 67842, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 7, 58399, 12346, 67848, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 8, 58394, 12341, 67844, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 9, 58398, 12348, 67847, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 10, 58396, 12349, 67841, '2015-02-06' ),
       ( 11, 58391, 12344, 67840, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 12, 58397, 12340, 67845, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 13, 58393, 12345, 67846, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 14, 58390, 12343, 67843, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 15, 58392, 12347, 67849, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 16, 58395, 12346, 67842, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 17, 58399, 12341, 67848, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 18, 58394, 12348, 67844, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 19, 58398, 12349, 67847, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 20, 58396, 12342, 67841, '2015-03-06' ),
       ( 21, 58391, 12340, 67840, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 22, 58397, 12345, 67845, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 23, 58393, 12343, 67846, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 24, 58390, 12347, 67843, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 25, 58392, 12346, 67849, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 26, 58395, 12341, 67842, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 27, 58399, 12348, 67848, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 28, 58394, 12349, 67844, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 29, 58398, 12342, 67847, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 30, 58396, 12344, 67841, '2015-04-06' ),
       ( 31, 58391, 12345, 67840, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 32, 58397, 12343, 67845, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 33, 58393, 12347, 67846, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 34, 58390, 12346, 67843, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 35, 58392, 12341, 67849, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 36, 58395, 12348, 67842, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 37, 58399, 12349, 67848, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 38, 58394, 12342, 67844, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 39, 58398, 12344, 67847, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 40, 58396, 12340, 67841, '2015-05-06' ),
       ( 41, 58391, 12345, 67840, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 42, 58397, 12343, 67845, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 43, 58393, 12347, 67846, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 44, 58390, 12341, 67843, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 45, 58392, 12348, 67849, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 46, 58395, 12349, 67842, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 47, 58399, 12342, 67848, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 48, 58394, 12344, 67844, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 49, 58398, 12340, 67847, '2015-07-06' ),
       ( 50, 58396, 12345, 67841, '2015-07-06' );
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y asi como esta, es imposible ayudarte... el error es claro una vez traducido... estas agregando en productos un proveedor que no existe en la tabla proveedores.. ahora, en donde de todo ese muro de codigo esta el problema? ni idea.. eso lo tendras que mirar vos haciendo las cosas de a una.. y por favor, usa los tags que corresponde, no cualquiera que encuentres...

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) gracias por mostrarnos datos de prueba. 2) Sin saber cómo están definidas las tablas, queda incompleto y sólo se puede adivinar. En resumen, como te dicen en la respuesta, todo está en el orden de inserción. Una FK exige que primero se inserte el registro en la tabla padre y luego en la tabla hija

Answer (score 0):

Según el error estás insertando productos que están relacionados con proveedores.

```
INSERT INTO t_productos (id_producto, modelo, marca, precio, id_proveedor) 
Values
       ( 12340, 'Camara', 'Sani', 5350, 45638 )....
```

El proveedor 45638, aún no lo has insertado, porque la sentencia de insert es posterior.

Por tanto la constraint que dice que todo producto tiene que estar relacionado con un proveedor, no se está cumpliendo.

Si insertas primero el proveedor 45638, esa regla ya se cumple y entonces pasaría correctamente.

Por tanto el bloque de productos y proveedores hay que invertirlo.

```
INSERT INTO t_proveedores (id_proveedor, nombre, apellido, dirección) 
Values
       ( 45630, 'Manuel', 'Hernández', 'calle coneja #432' ),
       ( 45631, 'Jesus', 'Martinez', 'calle flores #543' ),
       ( 45632, 'Fernanado', 'Lopez', 'calle trejo #654' ),
       ( 45633, 'Ivan', 'Sanchez', 'calle nuvo #765' ),
       ( 45634, 'Rosa', 'Rodriguez', 'calle trolo #876' ),
       ( 45635, 'Merida', 'Rito', 'calle falco #987' ),
       ( 45636, 'Leslie', 'Duran', 'calle mediterraneo #102' ),
       ( 45637, 'Ulises', 'Mendoza', 'calle mar #234' ),
       ( 45638, 'Andrea', 'Guzman', 'calle yate #345' ),
       ( 45639, 'Luz', 'Velazquez', 'calle siempre viva #678' );

INSERT INTO t_productos (id_producto, modelo, marca, precio, id_proveedor) 
Values
       ( 12340, 'Camara', 'Sani', 5350, 45638 ),
       ( 12341, 'Pantalla', 'Samsoni', 7820, 45632 ),
       ( 12342, 'Audifonos', 'Tronic', 1456, 45633 ),
       ( 12343, 'DVD', 'Yashi', 1000, 45631 ),
       ( 12344, 'Bluray', 'Moshi', 2000, 45636 ),
       ( 12345, 'Celular', 'Moma', 5670, 45639 ),
       ( 12346, 'Mouse', 'Razor', 560, 45630 ),
       ( 12347, 'Laptop', 'vopoi', 17500, 45635 ),
       ( 12348, 'Teclado', 'Razor', 1020, 45634 ),
       ( 12349, 'Videogame', 'Sanor', 4567, 45637 );
```